# Как в этом коде, сделать так, что бы при вводе отрицательного числа выводилось не "сколько минут вы были в душе", а любое другое сообщение?

Tags: c++, c

```
int main(void)
{
    int water = 0;
    {
        do
         {
            printf("Сколько минут вы были в душе?\n");
            scanf("%d", &water);
         }
        while (water <= 0);
         {
            int бутылки = water*12;
            printf("Вы потратили %i бутылок воды!\n", бутылки);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: А почему не подходит `if`?

Comment: Потому что if не запрашивает данные у пользователя еше раз

Answer (score 1):

Например, ваш `printf` внутри `do { ... } while` можно немного модифицировать

```
printf("%s%s\n", water ? "нормально отвечайте на вопрос -- " : "", "Сколько минут вы были в душе?");
```

Первый раз (при `water = 0`) увидите

```
Сколько минут вы были в душе?
```

а при вводе отрицательного числа вас немного подтолкнут в нужном направлении.

---

Конечно, возвращаемый `scanf` результат (при вводе числа это 1, при конце ввода (на клавиатуре нажали `^D`(или `^Z` в винде)) будет `EOF`, а если ввели не число, то 0), обязательно надо проверить и адекватно обработать.

Comment: Не совсем понятен синтаксис.  в частности "?" и пустые ковычки.

Comment: `?` это тернарный оператор. Слева условие, если оно true, то выполняется (тут берется строка) выражение  слева от `:`, а при false -- справа. Пустая строка `""` это для первого сообщения в цикле, поскольку при входе  в него water = 0 (0 это всегда false в C/C++, а не 0 -- true). Строка, выбираемая оператором `?` печатается первым `%s` в printf, а следующая строка (она всегда будет печататься), вторым `%s` в нем.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь с комментариями - чем вам `if` не угодил?
И код меньше ->

```
int main(void) 
{
    int time;
    std::cout <<"Сколько минут вы были в душе?\n";
    std::cin >> time;
    if(time >= 0)
        std::cout << "Вы потратили " << time * 12 << " буты(лок/ки) воды!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Вы экономите воду! +" << time * -12 << " бутылок воды!\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Теперь код выглядит так:

```
    int main(void)
   {
   int water = 0;
    printf("Сколько минут вы были в душе?\n");
    scanf("%d", &water);
    while (water <= 0)
    {
        printf("Грязный лжец! Сколько минут ты был в душе?\n");
        scanf("%d", &water);
    }
    int bot = water*12;
    printf("Вы потратили %i бутылок воды!\n", bot);
}
```

Comment: А теперь попробуйте ввести вместо числа любую букву...

Comment: Да. Цикл будет повторяться вечно. Но как сделать похожий "интерактив" с do-while циклом я пока что не знаю

Comment: Хотя нет. Решил проблему замени scanf("%d", &water); на water = GetInt():

Comment: Откоренно говоря, не знаю, что за функция GetInt() (в моем Linux такой нет). Вообще-то, надо просто обрабатывать код, возвращаемый [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: Если scanf только принимает любые введенные данные и присваивает их  переменной "water", то GetInt запрашивает эти данные и ожидает, что этими данными будет int - целое число

Comment: Мой уровень знания языка С - 5 лекций CS50. И какие--то манипуляции с кодом для меня еще очень сложны

Comment: И какое значение оказывается в water, если ввести, скажем, `q`? Ну, уровень знаний, надеюсь, будет расти по ходу написания программ (и чтения документации)

Comment: Переменная не принимает это значение. Ведь она ожидает ввода целого числа (int). Видимо так настроен IDE. 
При вводе отрицательного, или 0 - запускается цикл while.
А при вводе буквенного символа - новое значение запрашивается уже непосредственное в самом терминале. Не знаю как еще объяснить.

**Сколько минут вы были в душе?
-2
Грязный лжец! Сколько минут ты был в душе?
q
Retry:**

Comment: Ага, кажется понятно. **Retry** выводится внутри `GetInt()`. По видимому, ваша задача это как раз реализовать подобное поведение в своем `do { ... } while` на основе `scanf()`. Т.е. смотрите и если scanf вернул 0, то выводите сообщение и посимвольно читаете ввод до `\n`, потом снова вызываете в цикле scanf. Если scanf вернул -1 (это EOF), то красиво завершаетесь.